# How to format my new drive the same as others

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, disk, format

I have some drives in my server. Back when I set these up I was using Ubuntu Desktop. Now I am using Ubuntu Server and I'm not quite sure how to format my new drive like I did my old ones. I'm not sure it really matters? But OCD.

My new drive is sdj

```
$ lsblk --output NAME,UUID,FSTYPE,SIZE,PTTYPE
NAME   UUID                                 FSTYPE     SIZE PTTYPE
loop0                                       squashfs  55.3M
loop1                                       squashfs  69.4M
loop2                                       squashfs  31.1M
loop3                                       squashfs    31M
loop4                                       squashfs  55.4M
loop5                                       squashfs  69.8M
sda                                                  111.8G gpt
├─sda1                                                   1M gpt
└─sda2 172838a7-b2bc-4113-b2f2-f0d3b6a8ea36 ext4     111.8G gpt
sdb    93da0084-063a-49f7-b913-7f64d8404250 ext4     223.6G
sdc                                                    9.1T gpt
└─sdc1 35d167b5-b6d5-471e-aaed-33c516b9b87c xfs        9.1T gpt
sdd                                                    9.1T gpt
└─sdd1 53f86816-a9be-44c2-bbf4-bba9ce2a9be1 xfs        9.1T gpt
sde                                                    1.8T gpt
└─sde1 3a5dcbdf-59d9-49d1-b45e-7516203a4d47 xfs        1.8T gpt
sdf                                                    1.8T gpt
└─sdf1 1d45dda3-b61c-4459-be8c-e878734f10cf xfs        1.8T gpt
sdg                                                    1.8T gpt
└─sdg1 ae516984-2e2f-4adb-ab3d-b822b9a67d99 xfs        1.8T gpt
sdh                                                    1.8T gpt
└─sdh1 d48a0a43-0307-42b3-bf11-5c16e5f89bed xfs        1.8T gpt
sdi                                                    1.8T gpt
└─sdi1 1ff9a553-578f-40d5-b666-cc4cf590cf4f xfs        1.8T gpt
sdj                                                    9.1T gpt
```

I have tried running `sudo mkfs.xfs -f /dev/sdj`... that removes the "gpt"

```
sdj    8f0e3185-a87b-42f6-8d8a-692d9b7e90f5 xfs        9.1T
```

I'd like to make the new drive the same just for consistency, assuming I didn't do the old ones "wrong".

Thanks,
Chris

EDIT: I have tried to set the table to gpt, then add a xfs partitions but something weird is happening... it thinks the disk is ntfs and atari...

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sdj
GNU Parted 3.3
Using /dev/sdj
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) mklabel gpt
Warning: The existing disk label on /dev/sdj will be destroyed and all data on this disk will be
lost. Do you want to continue?
Yes/No? yes
(parted) mkpart primary xfs 0% 100%
(parted) print
Model: ATA WDC WD101EMAZ-11 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdj: 10.0TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  10.0TB  10.0TB               xfs

(parted) quit
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

$ lsblk --output NAME,UUID,FSTYPE,SIZE,PTTYPE
NAME   UUID                                 FSTYPE     SIZE PTTYPE
loop0                                       squashfs  55.3M
loop1                                       squashfs  69.4M
loop2                                       squashfs  31.1M
loop3                                       squashfs    31M
loop4                                       squashfs  55.4M
loop5                                       squashfs  69.8M
sda                                                  111.8G gpt
├─sda1                                                   1M gpt
└─sda2 172838a7-b2bc-4113-b2f2-f0d3b6a8ea36 ext4     111.8G gpt
sdb    93da0084-063a-49f7-b913-7f64d8404250 ext4     223.6G
sdc                                                    9.1T gpt
└─sdc1 35d167b5-b6d5-471e-aaed-33c516b9b87c xfs        9.1T gpt
sdd                                                    9.1T gpt
└─sdd1 53f86816-a9be-44c2-bbf4-bba9ce2a9be1 xfs        9.1T gpt
sde                                                    1.8T gpt
└─sde1 3a5dcbdf-59d9-49d1-b45e-7516203a4d47 xfs        1.8T gpt
sdf                                                    1.8T gpt
└─sdf1 1d45dda3-b61c-4459-be8c-e878734f10cf xfs        1.8T gpt
sdg                                                    1.8T gpt
└─sdg1 ae516984-2e2f-4adb-ab3d-b822b9a67d99 xfs        1.8T gpt
sdh                                                    1.8T gpt
└─sdh1 d48a0a43-0307-42b3-bf11-5c16e5f89bed xfs        1.8T gpt
sdi                                                    1.8T gpt
└─sdi1 1ff9a553-578f-40d5-b666-cc4cf590cf4f xfs        1.8T gpt
sdj                                                    9.1T gpt
└─sdj1 F8465D75465D361A                     ntfs       9.1T atari
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are formatting the `/dev/sdj` device, but not a partition like you did before.

So do this:

1. Create gpt partition table on your disk.
2. Create a partition (`/dev/sdj1`).
3. Format `/dev/sdj1` to `xfs`.

But it is OK to use a whole device without a partition table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you take a look at my edit and see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You've formatted `/dev/sdj1` to `ntfs` ;-) that looks wrong. Run `sudo mkfs.xfs -f /dev/sdj1`

Comment: Perfect thank you.